# Use text as java code in an app?

Tags: java

Right now I'm trying to make my app so that a certain section can be modified by the user. I want the part that can be modified to be in a text file, and make the app read that text file as code and execute it. How can I do this?

EDIT: My app loads java files that people made based on my app. I thought that if somebody called the constructor in the main class that starts their part of the app, it would overwrite my main class and other people's work wouldn't be loaded. How could I make it so that somebody could put
    Example example = new Example();
in a data file so that they could enable/disable their work and anybody else's?

EDIT 2: I have a class with a constructor in it. In the main class, I call the constructor.

```
Example example = new Example();
```

In the decompiled java file, there is supposed to be code that calls a constructor. When people develop things based on my software, they add code to the decompiled java file to make their part work. It would be basically like adding code to the main class.

FINAL EDIT: I stopped trying to this and instead made my own custom class loader. It reads a text file and sees the name of the class to load, converts the string into a class, finds a specific method in the class, and calls it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you trying to load Java code, or .class files?

Answer (score 2):

Better and **easier** to allow the user to edit a **data** file, and then have your program use that data to alter its behavior. For more specific help, please post more specific background information/context.

Comment: @Noodly_Doodly: Your question may fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. You're still not telling us the details of what your program does or what the other folks "code" should do.

Answer (score 1):

You can load additional class files with the help of a classloader, and then use reflection to instantiate them and invoke methods.  (Or if the class implements an interface you've already loaded in your application, you can just invoke the methods of that interface directly, without using reflection.)

Note that to use a classloader, you need a class file.  If all you have is a Java file, you'll need to use a compiler to transform it into a class file before you load it with the classloader.

Comment: I'll gave you a 1+ for this. It's hard to know what he wants at this stage.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Agreed, and you're right that this could definitely be an XY problem.  Your suggestion's definitely the approach I'd take if he just wants to change certain pre-defined things about the functionality, though the post as currently written seems to have a wider scope than that.

Comment: @Tim: I need to load a java file so that the user could add a line to it, and then the app would load that java file as code into the app, instead of me actually writing it into the main class.

Comment: @Tim: If this helps at all, it's sort of like a plugin system, and to answer your other question, it'll be using java files, not class files.

Comment: Classloaders are exactly what plugins use to load code that the main app doesn't know about, so I think this is what you want.

Comment: Also, my question about Java files vs. class files came because you wrote "My app loads class files that people made based on my app", so you might want to edit your question to fix that.

Comment: The thing is, I need it to read decompiled java files, so that anyone could modify it and the app would act like it was code written into the app. Like a link to code for the app that is not in the app, if you get what I mean.

Comment: Does the fact that the Java files happen to be decompiled change anything about the path you need to take forward?  I don't see anything you've written that changes the fact that you need to compile the new code using an on-the-fly compiler and then load the resulting class using a classloader, as I said in my answer.  Am I missing some nuance of your question?

Comment: I need this file to be editable, that way anybody who uses my app or develops for it can control what is called. I'm adding something right now to my original post.

Comment: Even after your Edit #2, I'm still not seeing anything that will preclude you from using the approach I've described.  But you're not going to be able to write `Example example = new Example()`, because you need to instantiate the class from within your helper classloader.  I'd recommend having that code implement an interface that's loaded in the primary classloader, so that once you've instantiated it (which will be slightly awkward), you can just use it normally thereafter.